# Schedule notification with alarm manager

Tags: android, alarmmanager, intentservice

I'm facing a little issue with my alarmManager. I'm trying to register an alarm to display a notification at spicified time. Here is how I'm doing it:

```
Utils.SetAlarm(this, Utils.GOODMORNING, 7, 0, 0); // so at 7:00
```

---

```
public static void SetAlarm(Context context, int req, int hour, int minute, int second) {
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, myService.class);
    intent.putExtra(ACTION_REQUEST, req);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, second);

    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
}
```

---

```
public class myService extends IntentService {
private static final int GOODMORNING_NOTIFICATION_REQUEST = 517;

public myService() {
    super("myService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    int extra = intent.getIntExtra(Utils.ACTION_REQUEST, 0);

    if (extra == Utils.GOODMORNING) {
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("title")
                .setContentText("content")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(GOODMORNING_NOTIFICATION_REQUEST, notification);
    }
}
```

---

The issue I'm facing is that the notifcation appear immediatly after i run the Utils.SetAlarm void. It will also appear fine at 7:00 am so it's apparently working but i wonder if someone known a way to avoid this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your were facing notification appear immediatly after you run the Utils.SetAlarm void.because of 7:00 am may have complete in your device so it's appears working at that instance.so try to set alarm for next day when current time is greater than alarm time

try this

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, second);
long time=calendar.getTimeInMillis();

if(time<System.currentTimeMillis()){
    time=time+AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY;
}

alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,time,
    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

Comment: i didn't test it out couse i'm a little busy with something else. But by reading the code seems like a possible working solution! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use following code for your solution : 
and i used comments so you can easily understand

```
// time at which alarm will be scheduled here alarm is scheduled at 1
// day from current time,
// we fetch the current time in milliseconds and added 1 day time
// i.e. 24*60*60*1000= 86,400,000 milliseconds in a day
Long time = selectedMilli;

// create an Intent and set the class which will execute when Alarm
// triggers, here we have
// given AlarmReciever in the Intent, the onRecieve() method of this
// class will execute when
// alarm triggers and
// we will write the code to send SMS inside onRecieve() method pf
// Alarmreciever class

Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(ScheduleActivity1.this,
        AlarmReciever.class);

// create the object
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this
        .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

// set the alarm for particular time
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, PendingIntent
        .getBroadcast(this, i, intentAlarm,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
/*
 * alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
 * time,TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
 * i, intentAlarm,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
 */
// alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
// time,AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, i,
// intentAlarm,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
// Toast.makeText(ScheduleActivity1.this,
// "Alarm Scheduled for " + selectedMilli, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
// .show();
```

Comment: this solution will loop the alarm every 30 seconds. I need to trigger it at specified time. My method is working fine except it send the intent when the alarm register